# Are there any shorter way to write codes for canvas html? I want to avoid using images if possible

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How to simplify this code without repeating the context? Are there any library for canvas api?
I tried using with(context), but it throws an error because I am using 'use strict'. Are there any way around this?

```
    context.save();
        context.beginPath();
        context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        context.translate(alien.x, alien.y);
        context.rotate(0);
        context.moveTo(-15, 0);
        context.lineTo(-15, 5);
        context.bezierCurveTo(-15, -10, 15, -10, 15, 5);
        context.lineTo(15, 0);
        context.lineTo(-15, 0);
        context.lineTo(-15, 5);
        context.lineTo(-20, 5);
        context.lineTo(-25, 10);
        context.lineTo(25, 10);
        context.lineTo(20, 5);
        context.lineTo(-20, 5);
        context.moveTo(10, 10);
        context.lineTo(10, 15);
        context.lineTo(15, 15);
        context.lineTo(15, 10);
        context.moveTo(-10, 10);
        context.lineTo(-10, 15);
        context.lineTo(-15, 15);
        context.lineTo(-15, 10);
        context.strokeStyle = '#fff';
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
        context.restore();
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's one way to concisely specify your canvas path data using SVG-like syntax.**

I yanked the following from an SVGPath-to-CanvasPath cross-compiler I wrote a while back. The nice thing about SVG path data is that it's very short & concise. It uses a single letter to define drawing command and it combines all the commands into a single string.

```
// Canvas path drawing commands represented by single command letters
  M == moveTo
  L == lineTo
  Q == quadraticCurveTo
  C == bezierCurveTo
  R == rect
  A == arc
  Z == closePath
  Y == clip
```

So your complex canvas path could be represented by a single short string like this:

`var data='M-15,0  L-15,5  C-15,-10,15,-10,15,5  L15,0  L-15,0  L-15,5  L-20,5  L-25,10  L25,10  L20,5  L-20,5  M10,10  L10,15  L15,15  L15,10  M-10,10  L-10,15  L-15,15  L-15,10';`

**Here's example code and a Demo that parses & draws this `data` string to the Canvas:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var commandExpander={
  M: 'moveTo',
  L: 'lineTo',
  Q: 'quadraticCurveTo',
  C: 'bezierCurveTo',
  R: 'rect',
  A: 'arc',
  Z: 'closePath',
  Y: 'clip'
}

// your path written as a single string
var data='M-15,0  L-15,5  C-15,-10,15,-10,15,5  L15,0  L-15,0  L-15,5  L-20,5  L-25,10  L25,10  L20,5  L-20,5  M10,10  L10,15  L15,15  L15,10  M-10,10  L-10,15  L-15,15  L-15,10';

// convert the single data string into separate commands
var commands=parseData(data);

// execute the drawing commands
definePath(commands);

// stroke the result
ctx.stroke();


// Take a single string containing path data
// Break it into separate commands and put all commands into an array
// One command consists of a letter and the command arguments
function parseData(data){

  var commands=[];

  var cmdSegments = data.match(/[a-z][^a-z]*/ig);        

  for(var i=0;i<cmdSegments.length;i++){

    var segment=cmdSegments[i];

    var command={letter:null,args:null};
    commands.push(command);

    command.letter=segment.slice(0,1);

    command.args=segment
    .slice(1)
    .trim()
    .replace(/-+/g,' -')
    .trim()
    .replace(/\s+/g,',')
    .replace(/,+/g,',')
    .split(",")
    .filter(function(e){return e!==''});

    for(var a=0;a<command.args.length;a++){
      command.args[a]=Number(command.args[a]);
    }

  }

  return(commands);   
}


// execute all the commands in the cmds[] array
function definePath(cmds){
  ctx.beginPath();
  for(var i=0;i<cmds.length;i++){
    var command=commandExpander[cmds[i].letter];
    var args=cmds[i].args;
    ctx[command].apply(ctx,args);
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a wrapper object - with this you can also shorten the names as well as extend functionality like setting color and line width at the same time calling stroke and so on.

**Update**: I also made **[this library](https://github.com/epistemex/ezcontext)** (free/MIT) which do wrapping of context.

Call them what you want - these are just examples of course. Make sure each one returns the `this` object which is what allows chaining. If you plan only to use a single instance you can put these methods inside the main object instead of using prototypes:

```
function CTX(ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
};
CTX.prototype.move = function(x,y) {this.ctx.moveTo(x, y); return this};
CTX.prototype.line = function(x,y) {this.ctx.lineTo(x, y); return this};
CTX.prototype.bez = function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) {
    this.ctx.bezierTo(a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
    return this;
};
// etc.
```

To use: just wrap your context with this instance:

```
var ctx = new CTX(context);

ctx .save()
    .begin()
    .setTrans(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
    .trans(alien.x, alien.y)
    .rot(0)
    .move(-15, 0)
    .line(-15, 5)
    .bez(-15, -10, 15, -10, 15, 5)
    .line(15, 0)
// etc.
```

```js
function CTX(ctx) {
  this.ctx = ctx;
};
CTX.prototype.begin = function() {
  this.ctx.beginPath();
  return this;
};
CTX.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  return this;
};
CTX.prototype.line = function(x, y) {
  this.ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  return this;
};

CTX.prototype.stroke = function(color) {
  if (color) this.ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  this.ctx.stroke();
  return this;
};
// ... define more here

var ctx = new CTX(canvas.getContext('2d'));

ctx
  .begin()
  .move(20, 20)
  .line(50, 50)
  .line(80, 20)
  .line(110, 50)
  .stroke('#00f');
  // etc.
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=500 height=180></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not have a default option for method chaining. Jquery does have this option, but not with the default Canvas methods (although there is a jCanvas plugin).

I think your best option is to write a method that executed a method with a set of arguments, which returns the context, so you can simulate chaining:

```
//Call on the canvas
//methodname is a string with the methodname;
//arguments is a list of arguments
canvas.prototype.applyMethodToContext = function(methodname, arguments){
    this[methodname].apply(this, arguments);
    return context;
}
```

This method is COMPLETELY untested and probably requires some changes to completely work. If you prefer to use a 3rd party solution which has been tested (and doesn't require entering the method as a string), someone has written a small javascript file (80 lines) that allows canvas chaining: https://github.com/millermedeiros/CanvasContext2DWrapper

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these site it just create a simple canvas for you  http://www.w3resource.com/html5/canvas-element.php